# Best way to run performance tests in a production PostgreSQL 13 database?

Tags: postgresql, locking, deadlock, dump, performance-testing

First, I'm asking this question because I'm studying to be a DBA. Recently I learned a lot about database locking, and then some questions arouse in my mind.

Suppose I'm a DBA, I'm in charge of a huge database from a online sales website. Some users reported that the site is slow, and my boss asks me to test the most used queries to see if they are running smooth or not. If I get locking right, if I just run an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on our `tb_products` I would probably lock it and it can have a negative impact on sales being processed at that time (i.e. some users could not buy their products because I'm "testing" queries).

My question is: how can I properly tests queries in a production database? In my (probably naive) way of thinking, what I need to do is to dump the database and its configurations, create a "sample" database with that and do the tests there. But them, if I'm testing locally on my machine, even with the same configs, numbers will differ, as we're testing on another hardware that's not the server hardware, right? I can't depict how can this tests be done when I think of it. It is probably a silly question, but any help to clarify that would be appreciated.

Comment: Please tag which database system and version.

Comment: PostgreSQL 13, but my question is about general concepts, not about a specifc database system.

Comment: You're probably better off changing one of your tags to it since tags are used for filtering, and someone filtering on the PostgreSQL tag *may* miss your question if you don't tag it accordingly.

Comment: I see. But in fact I just wanna know in general how can I test queries in a production database. My expectation is that, with this general answer, I can get clues about what I should read to get the specifics for Postgres. I think many DBAs here can explain to me how they approach these problem when they face it, like saying "oh, when I need to do this, I use THIS tool or I do THIS stuff". And them I can read about THIS in Postgres.

Comment: It varies from database system to database system, both approach and tools available, which is why listing the database system is important to know. For example, `EXPLAIN EXISTS` doesn't exist in the Microsoft SQL Server database system. That being said, the first step is generally the same across most relational database systems, which is analyzing the query plan - which is what `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` provides, and in other database systems there are other tools / methodologies that provide in a similar manner.

Comment: "*if I just run an EXPLAIN ANALYZE on our tb_products I would probably lock it*" - no. A plain SELECT does not lock a table. In Postgres, readers never block writers and writers never block readers.

Comment: I'm not saying that my EXPLAIN ANALYZE would be a SELECT. Consider that I'm testing a UPDATE query with the EXPLAIN ANALYSE, it will lock the table, or even an INSERT. What I'm trying to understand is: how can I test this queries in a production database?

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you should mimic the real life usage of the production online sales website on [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) level using a suitable [load testing tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) which supports HTTP (and maybe other protocols which might be used)

Given you run a [stress test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing) like starting with 1 user and gradually increase the load the store website will be generating more and more concurrent queries so you would be able to inspect the [slow query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html) or [deadlocks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html)

With regards to where to run the test, it's not a good idea to run the test against a scaled-down environment so if you cannot use the production server for tests (i.e. during night or weekend) you should restore the database backup against the server having the same hardware resources and the database engine configuration as the production one so it would be an exact replica.